# jQuery click event not working with setInterval replacing link

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, setinterval

I am making an incremental game in javascript, so I am replacing some links in the page all the time, this links are showing a really weird behavior. I am attaching the click events with .on(, and some times the click event is fired and some times not, is very random.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MtR6b/1/) is a clear example of the beheavior. I can imagine that is something related with the time interval, because if I set the interval in 1000 millis, the event always is fired. Of course that I can make some changed in the code in order to don't replace the link and only update it, but I want to know if this is fixable first.

HTML:

```
<div id="container"><a id="link" href="#">test</a></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#container").on("click","#link",function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
setInterval(function(){
    var newA = $("#link").clone();
    $("#link").remove();
    $("#container").append(newA);
},100);});
```

Example in jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/MtR6b/1/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Your `setInterval` code is very fast `100 ms` that's why when then event is about to trigger element is `replaced` with new one so `click event` is not `triggered`.

Try `clicking` on the link `many times` you will see the `alert`.

---

[DEMO with 1000ms=1s setInterval](http://jsfiddle.net/MtR6b/4/)

Comment: Yes I know that with 1 second works, but for example try with 500 ms, 500 ms is a LOT of time, and some times the event is not fired.